# Help with animation

Tags: jquery, animation, slider

I've used the "FeatureList" Jquery Plugin to make my own content slider.

The script can be found here: http://pastebin.com/7iyE5ADu

Here is an exemplificative image to show what I'm triyng to achieve: http://i41.tinypic.com/6jkeq1.jpg

Actually the slider add a "current" class to an item (in the example the squares 1,2 and 3) and for each thumb show a content in the main area.

In the example, with an interval of 2 seconds, the script switch from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, and so on.

I'd like to make a continuous animation of the thumbs, anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you seen my updated code! it support multiple items! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO:** http://aseptik.net/demo/help-with-animation

```
$(function() {
    //go trought each LI
    $('#tabs > li').each(function(i) {
        // and Add incremental ID to each one...
        $(this).attr('id', i + 1);
    });
    //set interval... and call function
    setInterval('swapImages()', 2000);
});
function swapImages() {
    var images = ['junku','codepoet','rappensuncle','nuomi','jam343','kk','ccgd','xdjio'];
    //count all LI's
    var total_lis = $('#tabs > li').size();
    // get the current LI ID based on where .current class...
    var start_pos = parseInt($('#tabs li a.current').parent().attr('id'));
    //remove the .current class for this LI...
    $('li#' + start_pos).children().attr('class', '');
    //calculate next LI ID...
    var next_pos = (start_pos < total_lis) ? start_pos + 1: 1;
    //add .current class to the new LI
    $('li#' + next_pos).children().attr('class', 'current');
    // monitor the position of current LI, if 3th OR multiple of the total do the magix...
    if ((start_pos == 3) || (start_pos % total_lis == 0) || (next_pos == total_lis)) {
        $('li#' + next_pos).prevAll().andSelf().attr('class', 'faded').fadeOut(200);
        $('li#' + next_pos).nextAll('.faded').andSelf().attr('class', '').fadeIn(200);
    }
    //Append some stuff recursive...
$('#output li').fadeOut(200,function() {
    $(this).html('<img src="http://l.yimg.com/g/images/home_photo_' + images[next_pos] + '.jpg" />' + '<a href="#">See project details</a>').fadeIn(200);
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my main problem is that I'd like to have more than 3 elements to slide. In your example imagine that below the "Applications"  there are other 3 tabs.
I'd like to have them scrolling down-to-up.

Comment: It is a nice implementation to get the current item in the list.

$('tabs li a.current')